# simulation nodes not updating the value of named attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm try to create a [particle effect](https://youtu.be/AlRPLdA_BLw), and the nodes that I've made accordingly should capture the radius, and on each frame the value of the stored attribute should be subtracted by `.001`, but, the value of the `lifetime` named attribute field I've stored doesn't get updated on each frame from `.020` it only goes to `.019`, which is I believe the update on the first frame. Is there something wrong with my node setup?:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is effectively an issue in your file. I don't know why for now, but I've updated the answer with a working setting, so that you/we may understand why this is not working with you file.

Comment: I think something is "broken" in your file. Don't know why but all attribute assignment are weird. I propose you redo it using last Blender version. Please comment here for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reasons indicated by Chris, named attribute node should be inside of the simulation, not pluged as a simulation input (or output).

Something around this:

[image]

Considering it has been initilize before you join new points. Something like this:

[image]

Example file (Blender 4.0):

[image]

---

The file you've uploaded works, simply change this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Because the map range node inverts the values so that the less is the input, the more is the output and in consequence, subtracting the value by 0.001 never reaches 0.

Comment: I did try to bring the named attribute inside the zone as suggested( https://pasteboard.co/iCxWgwlTibuW.png ) , but, neither the geometry is being deleted nor the radii of any points are shrinking

Comment: In this setting, you should give an initial positive value to the named attribute. If not you should invert things: increment at each step and delete above a positive value.

Comment: Note that I've not copied the video tutorial, the effect can be done either decrementing (starting from a given value) or incrementing from a 0 value.

Comment: somehow worked in 3.6 with the fix mentioned above... thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

this happens because simulation zone is looping inside. The value which go in the simulation output, come back with exactly the same values in the simulation input at the next frame.
Because you didn't change/connect the attribute (it is always 0) in simulation output, at the next frame the attribute in simulation input is 0 (always zero) except for the very first frame, where you input the lifetime value, but as you don't fill it, it is zero at the first frame as well.
The rest is math: 0 comes from Sim input, mapped gives 0.02, subtract 0.001 gives 0.019 and this will be store in lifetime forever.

Remember: the value which go INTO simulation input, are just for the very first frame. After that the values will be take from the simulation output.

So the solution is: you have to connect something to the attribute in the simulation output node.

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for replying. As you suggested, I connected the output of the subtract node in the simulation output and used that as input to my set radius node, but, it still didn't change anything. Also, in the linked video above, [4:46], he also doesn't input anything to the simulation output node but the radius does shrink. I also connected the attribute of the named attribute directly to the simulation output instead since that should change due to the subtract node, but it still doesn't change anything

Comment: ok, then pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: I've attached the .blend in the question, although I've implemented @lemon 's version as I was also trying out his approach